# Refresh page on AJAX Update Panel failure

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm running a site that shows the status of multiple servers as well as info regarding the number of users in a few different systems.  I'm using an AJAX UpdatePanel triggered by an asp:Timer control to refresh the data.

This works sometimes for days, other times just hours, but inevitably, the process fails and the refreshes stop.  At this point, I need manually refresh the page via the browser and things will then continue to work until the next failure.

I'm looking for a way to refresh the page if the data appears stale.  I'm considering adding a hidden value on the page that is updated with the data. If I detect this data as old, I can trigger a page refresh.  However, don't I run the risk of this script failing?  The only difference is I won't have the ASP/AJAX bloat included with the Script Manager, Update Panel and Timer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following meta tag to force a refresh every two hours.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7200" /> <!--Refresh every two hours-->
```

This isn't ideal, as I would prefer to refresh only when the data was stale. Unfortunately, when my data would go stale, it was due to failure ajax update panel.  It seemed that when the AJAX panel stopped working, so did the javascript code I put in place to detect stale data.

In any case, this is working and has been for a few months now so I thought I would post this as the answer.